# Livewire Array Instant Validation

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-6, laravel-livewire

I am trying out Livewire's instant authentication which seems to work fine for other inputs but array fields. Wondering how I could show the error messages for array inputs.
Blade code

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]+" minlength="6" wire:model="contact_phone.{{$index}}"
       class="form-control {{ $errors->has('contact_phone.*') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }} " required>
<div>@error('contact_phone') <span class="error text-danger small">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror</div>
```

Validation

```
public function updated($field)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($field, [ 
            'contact_phone' => 'required|array|min:1',
            'contact_phone.*' => 'required|string|min:3',
        ]);

    }
```

Following this [doc](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/input-validation)

Comment: Reuben, your input is for "contact_phone" and your validation is for "contact_name"; maybe this is your issue? Otherwise, please post the correct code, thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question now

Answer (score 1):

This is how I finally got it to work. The key was to access the index of the specific array input in @error directive.

```
<input type="tel" pattern="[0-9]+" minlength="6" wire:model.lazy="contact_phone.{{$index}}"
       class="form-control {{ $errors->has('contact_phone.'.$index) ? ' is-invalid' : '' }} " required>
<div>@error('contact_phone.{{$index}}')
    <span class="error text-danger small">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror
</div>
```